# Azure Managed storage account communication happens over public or private endpoint

Tags: storage, account, managed

Can we enable private endpoint for managed storage account and does the communication happen over Private or public endpoint for the account.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For a managed Storage account created for Virtual machine, can we enable Private endpoint.